# possible to increase speed of power function applied to a vector?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to increase speed of power function applied to a vector?

```
N=16e3;
X=-2+4*rand(N,1);
Y=10.^X;
```

I tried:

```
Y=power(10,X);
```

But of course it gives me the same speed. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no difference between `power` and `.^`. They both refer to the same functionality internally.  I don't expect this function to be slower.     Why do you think it is not fast enough? Are you really sure it is the bottleneck of your code?

Comment: That code takes 5ms to run in a normal computer (mine is quite average). Are you sure that is what you need to optimize?

Comment: Cross-link to Matlab Answers: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/408369-possible-to-increase-speed-of-power-function-applied-to-a-vector

Comment: Yes, I am sure this is one of the major bottlenecks. I'm running this line thousands of times (1000-10000 times), and I cannot pass the input as a matrix because the values to pass are calculated at previous time steps in my code.

Comment: Running the code 10e3 times required 7.4 s on my machine, which is ~20% of the total running time of my application.

Answer (score 1):

using gpuArray does it 4 times fater on my machine

```
N=16e3;
X=-2+4*rand(N,1);

f = @() 10.^X;
t = timeit(f)

X=gpuArray(X);
f = @() 10.^X;
t = timeit(f)
```

Comment: exactly the same for me in an average CPU (some i5) with an average GPU (1050 GTX).

Comment: matlab version perhaps? I use 2017b on linux with i7 CPU and  GTX 960

Comment: I was just agreeing with you, sorry. I meant exactly the same results that you get.

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2015b and I encounter a problem when trying to use the gpuArray function.

---------
There is a problem with the CUDA driver or with this GPU device. Be sure
that you have a supported GPU and that the latest driver is installed.

Caused by:
    The CUDA driver could not be loaded. The library name used was
    'nvcuda.dll'. The error was:
    The specified module could not be found.
---------

When following the links proposed in the error, I'm forwarded to this website
https://ch.mathworks.com/products/availability.html

It's a bit confusing to me...